# Why does GridView need a BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, android-adapter

Why do we need `BaseAdapter` in `GridView`? Why base adapter itself? Can we use some other adapter type?

```
public class ImageButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter
  {


  }
```

Comment: am really sorry if u cant follow the message am really new to this..so really sorry guys...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any type of adapter that extends `BaseAdapter`, so the `ImageButtonAdapter` in your post would work. 
The GridView is basically a list that displays its item in a grid, and in Android lists use an `Adapter` to get their data. This is why you need the adapter.

Comment: is there any particular reason for using base adapter as base class..? coz if am right then adapter is base class and array adapter, base adapter simple adapter are all sub clases... correct me if am wrong.. and thanks for ur reply..

Comment: `BaseAdapater` is an abstract class implementing `SpinnerAdapter` and `ListAdapter`. The `ArrayAdapter` and `SimpleAdapter` both extends the `BaseAdapter`. This means that you can use both an ArrayAdapter or a SimpleAdapter, or a custom implementation.  If the GridView only took a SimpleAdapter for example, you could not use your own implementation of BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

This is implemetation of standard pattern [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

> the Model: the domain objects or data structures that represent the application's state
>
> the View, which observes the state and generates output to the users.
>
> the Controller, which translates user input into operations on the model

You have `List<YourObject> objects`  - this is "Model"

Adapter which inherits from BaseAdater is "Controller". It controlls presentation of your "Model"

GridView is a "View". It provides presentation of "Model"